# D3 - How do I filter the right values with opacity?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter, opacity

I am having trouble understanding and implementing the filter functionality for nodes. My goal is to only show specific nodes (opacity = 1) and let the other nodes be invisible (opacity = 0). Here is the js fiddle down below and a snippet of the filter function.

https://jsfiddle.net/1a270e23/

```
d3.selectAll(".filterBtn").on("change", function() {
    var type = this.value,
    opacity = this.checked ? 1 : 0,
    aDates = d3.select("#allDates").node().checked,
    fDate = d3.select("#fDates").node().checked,
    sDate = d3.select("#sDates").node().checked;

    svg.selectAll(".item").filter(function(d) {
        if(type === "aD") {
            if(aDates) {
                document.getElementById("fDates").checked = true;
                document.getElementById("sDates").checked = true;
                return d;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("fDates").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("sDates").checked = false;
                return d;
            }
        } else if(type === "fD") {
            var d1 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-01"));
            var d2 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-02"));
            var d3 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-03"));
            var d4 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-04"));
            var d5 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-05"));

            if(d - d1 === 0 || d - d2 === 0 || d - d3 === 0 || d - d4 === 0 || d - d5 === 0) {
                if(fDate) {
                    opacity = 1;
                } else {
                    opacity = 0;
                }
                return d;
            } else {
                //Other nodes <-- I don't want to show them
                //RETURN STATEMENT 1
                opacity = 0;
                return d;
            }

        } else {
            var d1 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-01"));
            var d2 = new Date(parseDate("1988-01-02"));
            if(d - d1 === 0 || d - d2 === 0) {
                if(sDate) {
                    opacity = 1;
                } else {
                    opacity = 0;
                }
                return d;
            } else {
                //Other nodes <-- I don't want to show them
                //RETURN STATEMENT 2
                opacity = 0;
                return d;
            }
        }
    })
    .attr("opacity", opacity);
});
```

What I can't seem to understand is when "opacity = 0" is taken out and return d; is replaced with return; THEN only the specific nodes appear, which I don't want to happen.

Here are the steps that I want to use to be able to see the filtered nodes.

1. Click All (so it unchecks)
2. Click on First Dates (so it is checked, thus showing the filtered nodes)

What I need to see are the specific nodes which I have filtered while using opacity = 0 and using return d;

If there is an alternative way to do this, please give me suggestions. Thank you!

Comment: Looking at this you havent defined differences between the data points. So all the data points are all first dates, second dates, and all dates. So trying to filter between isnt working because there is no difference between them. Unless Im missing something, like what dates are the firstDates?

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks for responding. The first dates are the first 5 dates in the list. The second dates are only the first two. If you take out opacity = 0 and return d; and replace it with just return; you will see the difference.

Comment: You don't need to filter, just put the selector function in the second argument of `.attr` but, move all of the logic for managing the check box state into the outer scope of the event listener. You are currently recalculating the same thing for each point...

Comment: @CoolBlue Thanks for replying. Can you please give me an example of what I should do? What do you mean by the selector function? May I also know why I don't need a filter. I'm sorry i'm confused :(

Comment: The way to get unconfined is to read the manual. There are many basic examples and a lot of documentation which pop up if you type "D3" into Google.  [here is a good place to start.](https://d3js.org/#properties)

Comment: @CoolBlue I checked out the manual did look up some examples. I did have a general idea what the examples were on filtering and checkboxes because I previously researched them. So what you're saying is the svg.selectAll should be in the second argument of the .attr and the management of the checkbox state should be inside the on change function right?

Comment: No, read the link in my previous message, the selector function I mean is the one selecting which elements to set what opacity. As explained in the link the second argument of the `attr` method can be a function of the data and you can use that to conditionally set the opacity.

Comment: @CoolBlue You helped me so much wow! Thank you. I'll update you soon. Once I do that you can put the answer in this thread and ill give you a check

Comment: @CoolBlue It works! :) Thank you. You can write up the answer if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you don't need to use `.filter` for this, you use the built in functionality for [Dynamic Properties](https://d3js.org/#properties).  The second argument in the `.attr` method can be a function and it will be passed datum that is bound to each element of your selection so that you can set the property conditionally, as a function of the datum.